# Flash going back to normal size after exiting fullscreen mode?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've made a flash application using actionscript 3,
I wanted this application size to be dynamic,

To be able to embed it in any size and let it adjust itself accordingly.

I managed to accomplish this, theres a problem though:

The original width of the application is 700 pixels.
I'm embedding the flash in a smaller size, (400 for example)
going to full screen, and when I exit, the application sets itself back to being 700 pixels wide, and isn't adjusting itself to the 400px width of the actual embedding area..

I hope that I made myself clear enough,
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
That's the code that toggles fullscreen modes in my application:

```
function fullScreenToggle(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(stage.displayState == "fullScreen"){
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    } else {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeDo);
```

Comment: Post your code, we can't very well debug it if we can't see it!

Comment: @grapefrukt Well it's quite a general question, I'll post a few things from it in a minute, the ones that control the fullscreen I guess

Comment: Well I figured it out myself,
What I did was simply put this line of code, to be run after the user exits the fullscreen mode.

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself, What I did was simply put this line of code, to be run after the user exits the fullscreen mode. stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;